# What is the meaning (definition) of "current-starving"?

Tags: transistors, design

In several circuit descriptions we can find the term „current-starved“, „current-starving“ or „voltage-starved“.

[Example](http://www.ripublication.com/aeee_spl/aeeev4n6spl_16.pdf)

In chapter 4 (Current-starved voltage-controlled oscillator) we can read:

> This VCO is designed using ring oscillator and its operation is also
>   similar to that. From the schematic circuit shown in the Fig.(3), it
>   is observed that MOSFETs M2 and M3 operate as an inverter, while
>   MOSFETs M1 and M4 operate as current sources. The current sources, M1
>   and M4, limit the current available to the inverter, M2 and M3; in
>   other words, the inverter is **starved** for the current.

From this, I derive that „current-starved“ is similar (or even identical?) to current-limiting. Is this correct? Does anybody know the definition of „starving“ in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something that goes near to a formal definition can be found in [this GoogleBook page](https://books.google.it/books?id=QgS7BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=current+starving+technique&source=bl&ots=BzY2tiyIfk&sig=emerze4F_1xrKUGXUcTfsPkUOZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwATgKahUKEwiW4sHO_K_HAhXGWBQKHQyLASs#v=onepage&q=current%20starving%20technique&f=false). Excerpt:

> Another way to control the delay of an inverter is to add two extra
>   transistors as shown in Fig.4.15a. This technique is also known as
>   *current starving*. Lowering Vn and increasing Vp increases the effective drive resistance Req of the inverter and thus increases the
>   delay. The voltages Vn and Vp can be generated  from the one control
>   current Ictrl using current mirrors as shown in Fig.4.15b.
>   Alternatively, the current source can be omitted, so that Vn can be
>   set externally and determines Vp. A third option is to leave both
>   voltages as external bias voltages. This allows tuning out any
>   differences in resistance between the nMOS and pMOS transistors as
>   well.
>
> [image]

Further searching on Google seems to confirm that the phrase "current starving" (or similar) mostly appear in the context of limiting the current of a digital-logic inverter of some sort.

In particular see this [Wikipedia article on ECL logic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic#Operation). Excerpt:

> At low input voltage (logical "0") or at high input voltage (logical
>   "1") the differential amplifier is overdriven. The one transistor (T1
>   or T3) is cutoff and the other (T3 or T1) is in active linear region
>   acting as a common-emitter stage with emitter degeneration that takes
>   all the current, starving the other cutoff transistor.

Another [GoogleBook reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=d-Mv4nxmaPMC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22current+starving%22+technique&source=bl&ots=nzi_3MNl_b&sig=xUhU1e8LR4oONxOdfkgj2oKx_Wc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCWoVChMIr8qQ7f-vxwIVhcAUCh07ow_z#v=onepage&q=%22current%20starving%22%20technique&f=false) states the following:

[image]

So it seems to me that *current starving* is not an exact synonym for *current limiting*, but it is a more specific term used when limiting applies to the output current of active elements for the purpose of altering their operating characteristics, in contrast to current limiting as a protection against overloads.

Comment: The last sentence of the above reply could serve as a definition - thank you. I think, this covers also the operation of the "starved circuit" in (http://electronicdesign.com/analog/starved-circuit-amplifier-revived-transistor-version). To me, the role of the extra BJT in this link (Fig.1) is something like "bootstrapping" with the aim to dynamically increase the gain determining resistor. Agreed?

Comment: After reading all your answers and comments - as well as some more contributions dealing with "current starving" - my (momentary) conclusion is the following: The last sentence of L. Donatis comment can serve as a good definition, provided we replace "limiting" by "controlling": ...when controlling applies to the current of an active elements for the purpose of altering their operating characteristics, in contrast to current limiting as a protection against overloads.

Comment: @LvW Yep, I think your definition is good, the "controlling" instead of "limiting" seems to hit the spot. I admittedly never heard the term "current starving" before and it doesn't seem to be something clearly defined in the literature, even if the concept seems what we agree upon here. The mysteries of the evolution of electronics! :-)

Comment: This sounds "reassuring" to me (correct term?) because I also have heard the expression "current starving" the first time only about 4 weeks ago .

Answer (score 3):

In this context "current-starved" means that the current through the circuit is indeed limited. A "normal" inverter is directly connected to the ground and supply rails. In theory it can draw as much current as it likes.

In this design, there's a currentmirror output in series with these connections. When the current that the inverter draws is less that the current mirror can supply, the current mirror output will be in triode mode, behave as a resistor and just pass the current. This situation is not much different from an inverter with connections to the supply lines (from the inverter's point of view).

Now assume the inverter wants to draw more current than the currentmirror outputs allow, then the current will be limited by the mirror's outputs. The inverter will be starved for current. As a result it will be slower as it cannot push/pull as much current at it's output. This results in a lower oscillation frequency of the ring oscillator (when compared to a non current starved situation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how the circuit operates. However, the "core" of my question is just the term "starved" in contrast to the common term "limited". Is there a difference in its usage? And if yes - where is the difference? As another example: BJT differential amplifier with a current mirror as an active load. Also "starved for current".

Comment: I would not call a BJT diffpair "starved for current". In the ringoscillator situation, the lack of current significantly changes the behaviour of the inverter, the inverter is stopped in doing what it wants to do. The BJT amp just clips. I guess the "starved" term is what the writer makes of it.

Comment: So - there is no clear definition of this term?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: http://electronicdesign.com/analog/starved-circuit-amplifier-revived-transistor-version; this link gives another example.